# Beginner at Javascript trying to connect it to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So Ive been trying to add two number together from two input boxes in my HTML file, and display the answer in a third input box.

Here is my code for the Javascript

```
var x;
var y;

 function Add() 
 {
     x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
     y = document.getElementById("input2").value;
document.getElementById("answer").value = x + y
}
```

Here is my code for the HTML file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Projects\Math Website\Math.css" />
<link href="Math.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Projects\Math Website\Maths.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<input type="text" id="input1">
<p>+</p>
<input type="text" id="input2">
<button  onclick="Add()" >Get Value</button>

<input type="text" id="answer">
</body>
  >  </html>
```

Basically through some help, I got rid of all the syntax errors but it still seems to not be able to add the two numbers? Can anyone help me? Also can anyone give me some more general advice on linking Javascript with HTML?

Comment: You still have a syntax error in the last line of your javascript function

Comment: I think it is not a standard question.

Comment: What do you mean?

Yeah, I tried changing it to what My Sajaya said. Still no results? Nothing seems to occur when I press the button

Answer (score 1):

In javascript "+" is used to concat the string

and the value return by `document.getElementById("id").value` will always return an `string`

so in order to apply real "+" operation you have to convert  these string to integer

and this can be done by using `parseInt`.

there are other also avilable like `parseFloat` to add the floating point number

```
document.getElementById("answer").value = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y)
```

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable when you would explain why this is necessary.

Comment: Yes, what does Parsing do?

Comment: I got it working!it seems that when i copy the script directly into the html file with the script tags it works! But there doesnt seem to be a problem linking the Javascript file with my HTML file? 
This website is amazing
Thank you for your help

Comment: Always nice to `parseInt(x, 10) `

Answer (score 0):

Correct your js code and parse it.

```
function Add() 
 {
     x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
     y = document.getElementById("input2").value;
     document.getElementById("answer").value = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but it still doesnt seem to work for me, I type in the two inputs but nothing seems to happen when I press the button?

also what does Parsing do?

Comment: Just as that of user3091574, your answer would be more valuable when you would explain why this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at doing a web dev beginners course at a site like codeacademy.com
basic problems just come from either skipping ahead and not covering the basics or ill practice. This at least will cover you not only this time but the next time too.